# JAVA: RMI method error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, rmi, nosuchmethoderror

I'm getting this error while executing the method chat in RMI:

```
    ...
    case talk:
    if(param!=null)
    {
       System.out.println("What do you want to say to "+param+"?");
       String msg=br.readLine();
       String room=myPG.getCurrentRoom();
       utils.chat(room,param,msg);
    }
    else
       System.out.println("Wrong usage: e.g. talk Ciccio");
    break;
    ...
```

The implementation of RMI method is very simple... but the error comes before entering into the method:

```
public void chat(String room,String name,String msg) throws RemoteException
    {
        System.out.println(room+name+msg);
    }
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: pgUtils.PGUtilsInterface.chat(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

EDIT: the remote object utils works fine with all the other remote methods that i use in my application, so... don't know what's happening.

Comment: @Owl thanks for taking care of that. I was starting to twitch.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a versioning error. The `*.class` file being used on one end of the connection doesn't have the method; you just need to do a bit of cleanup and try again.

Comment: Was scratching my head for a long time.